# DB2 SQL Multiple Trigger Cascade

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

As above title mentioned.
Assuming I have 3 table.

```
--table A, B, C
```

and two trigger that are meant to cascade:

```
--trigger X, Y
create trigger X
after insert on A
...(some codes)
update B set ...(some codes);

--and
create trigger Y
after update on B
...(some codes)
insert into C values ( ...(some codes));
```

where:

```
--insert on A fire X to update B, then again fire Y to insert on C.
```

But the problem is first trigger X was fired without problem but second trigger Y is not being fired after the first.

What may be the problem with above code?

For my project, I'm creating a mini Warehouse database to test out all the entity. Below is the code I have done so far.

```
--create tables, no error over here i assumed
CREATE TABLE VENUE(
VENUE_ID        DECIMAL(3,0) NOT NULL CHECK (VENUE_ID BETWEEN 111 AND 333),
VENUE_FLOOR     INT NOT NULL CHECK (VENUE_FLOOR IN (1,2,3)),
VENUE_SECTION   INT NOT NULL CHECK (VENUE_SECTION IN (1,2,3)),
PRIMARY KEY (VENUE_ID)
)@

CREATE TABLE CLIENT(
    CLIENT_ID       DECIMAL(5,0) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 10000 INCREMENT BY 1) CHECK (CLIENT_ID BETWEEN 10000 AND 99999),
    CLIENT_FNAME    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CLIENT_LNAME    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CLIENT_PHONE    VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    CLIENT_ADDRS    VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CLIENT_ID),
    CONSTRAINT CLIENT_PHONE_UNQ UNIQUE (CLIENT_PHONE)
)@

CREATE TABLE COURIER(
    COURIER_ID      DECIMAL(3,0) NOT NULL CHECK (COURIER_ID BETWEEN 100 AND 999),
    COURIER_FNAME   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    COURIER_LNAME   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    COURIER_PHONE   VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (COURIER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT COURIER_PHONE_UNQ UNIQUE (COURIER_PHONE)
)@

CREATE TABLE STOCK(
    STOCK_ID        DECIMAL(8,0) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 10000000 INCREMENT BY 1) CHECK (STOCK_ID BETWEEN 10000000 AND 19999999),
    STOCK_NAME      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    SUPPLIER_NAME   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    STOCK_QTY       INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    VENUE_ID        DECIMAL(3,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (STOCK_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (VENUE_ID) REFERENCES VENUE ON DELETE no action,
    CONSTRAINT STOCK_NAME_UNQ UNIQUE (STOCK_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SUPPLIER_NAME_UNQ UNIQUE (SUPPLIER_NAME)
)@

--CREATE TRIGGER/PROCEDURE CHECK STOCK_QTY - ORDER_QUANTITY >= 100-- 
CREATE TABLE ORDER(
    ORDER_ID        DECIMAL(11,0) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 10000000000 INCREMENT BY 1) CHECK (ORDER_ID BETWEEN 10000000000 AND 99999999999),
    ORDER_QTY       INT NOT NULL CHECK (ORDER_QTY BETWEEN 10 AND 999),
    CLIENT_ID       DECIMAL(5,0) NOT NULL,
    STOCK_ID        DECIMAL(8,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CLIENT_ID) REFERENCES CLIENT(CLIENT_ID) ON DELETE no action,
    FOREIGN KEY (STOCK_ID) REFERENCES STOCK(STOCK_ID) ON DELETE no action
)@

CREATE TABLE DELIVERY(
    DELIVERY_ID     DECIMAL(11,0) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 16900000000 INCREMENT BY 1) CHECK ( DELIVERY_ID BETWEEN 16900000000 AND 16999999999 ),
    ORDER_ID        DECIMAL(11,0) NOT NULL,
    COURIER_ID      DECIMAL(3,0),
    PRIMARY KEY(DELIVERY_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(ORDER_ID)REFERENCES ORDER(ORDER_ID) ON DELETE no action,
    FOREIGN KEY(COURIER_ID)REFERENCES COURIER(COURIER_ID) ON DELETE no action,
    CONSTRAINT ORDER_ID_DELI_UNQ UNIQUE (ORDER_ID)
)@

--TO SELECT FOR LOG- USE SELECT TIMESTAMP(LOG_ID), ... FROM LOG@
CREATE TABLE LOG(
    LOG_ID          CHAR(13) NOT NULL FOR BIT DATA,
    LOG_PROCESS     VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL CHECK (LOG_PROCESS IN ('Stock-in','Stock-out')),
    LOG_QTY         INT NOT NULL CHECK(LOG_QTY BETWEEN 10 AND 999),
    LOG_DATE        DATE NOT NULL,
    DELIVERY_ID     DECIMAL(11,0),
    STOCK_ID        DECIMAL(8,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(LOG_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(DELIVERY_ID)REFERENCES DELIVERY(DELIVERY_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(STOCK_ID)REFERENCES STOCK(STOCK_ID)
    --CONSTRAINT DELIVERY_ID_LOG_UNQ UNIQUE (DELIVERY_ID)
)@
```

insert some value to test:

```
--INSERT INTO TABLE--
INSERT INTO VENUE VALUES (111,1,1)@
INSERT INTO VENUE VALUES (112,2,2)@
INSERT INTO VENUE VALUES (113,3,3)@

INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES (DEFAULT,'ROAN','CHENG','60189774541','28 JLN APA')@
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES (DEFAULT,'AAA','ABC','60101234567','29 JLJ AAA')@
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES (DEFAULT,'BBB','BBC','60111234567','30 JLN BBB')@

INSERT INTO COURIER VALUES (100,'DHL','EXP','60355006666')@
INSERT INTO COURIER VALUES (200,'ABX','EXP','60344007777')@
INSERT INTO COURIER VALUES (300,'POS','LAJU','61300882525')@

INSERT INTO STOCK VALUES (DEFAULT,'IPHONE 7','APPLE',100,111)@
INSERT INTO STOCK (STOCK_ID,STOCK_NAME,SUPPLIER_NAME,VENUE_ID) VALUES (10000001,'SAMSUNG S7','SAMSUNG',112)@
INSERT INTO STOCK VALUES (DEFAULT,'MMU','TM',300,113)@
INSERT INTO STOCK VALUES (DEFAULT,'CINEMA','TGV',200,111)@
INSERT INTO STOCK VALUES (DEFAULT,'FOO','FOOCORP',1000,113)@

INSERT INTO ORDER VALUES (DEFAULT,10,10000,10000003)@
INSERT INTO ORDER VALUES (DEFAULT,20,10000,10000002)@
INSERT INTO ORDER VALUES (DEFAULT,30,10002,10000002)@
```

and the trigger part, with correct order for the cascade layer

```
--TRIGGER--
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--1)AUTO CREATE DELIVERY AFTER PLACING ORDER (no error)
CREATE TRIGGER REQUEST_DELIVERY
AFTER INSERT ON ORDER
REFERENCING NEW AS N
for each row mode db2sql
INSERT INTO DELIVERY VALUES (
    DEFAULT,
    N.ORDER_ID,
    NULL
)@

--2)UPDATE STOCK QTY AFTER ISSUED A SUCCESSFUL DELIVERY (UPDATE DELIVERY WITH COURIER_ID MEANS PARCEL HAS
--  BEEN MAILED OUT)
--(error here, sqlstate="21000" & "09000",for trigger "...UPDATELOG)
drop trigger UPDATESTOCK_STOCKOUT@
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATESTOCK_STOCKOUT
AFTER UPDATE OF COURIER_ID ON DELIVERY
REFERENCING OLD AS O
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN
    UPDATE STOCK
    SET STOCK_QTY = STOCK_QTY - (SELECT ORDER_QTY FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID)
    WHERE STOCK_ID IN (SELECT STOCK_ID FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID);
END@


--NOT WORKING EITHER FOR BELOW ALTERNATIVES--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATEDELIVERY(IN ORD_ID DECIMAL(11,0), COU_ID DECIMAL(3,0))
BEGIN
    UPDATE DELIVERY SET COURIER_ID = COU_ID WHERE ORDER_ID = ORD_ID;
    --UPDATE STOCK SET STOCK_QTY = STOCK_QTY - (SELECT ORDER_QTY FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER.ORDER_ID = ORD_ID);
END@

DROP PROCEDURE UPDATEDELIVERY2@
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATEDELIVERY2(IN DLV_ID DECIMAL(11,0), COU_ID DECIMAL(3,0))
BEGIN
    UPDATE DELIVERY SET COURIER_ID = COU_ID WHERE DELIVERY_ID = DLV_ID;
    --UPDATE STOCK SET STOCK_QTY = STOCK_QTY - (SELECT ORDER_QTY FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER.ORDER_ID = (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM DELIVERY D WHERE D.DELIVERY_ID = DLV_ID))
    --WHERE STOCK_ID = (SELECT STOCK_ID FROM ORDER O, DELIVERY D WHERE D.DELIVERY_ID = DLV_ID AND D.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID);
END@

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--3)auto update delivery.COURIER_ID once stock out in log
--(error here, sqlstate="21000" & "09000",for trigger "...UPDATELOG)
drop trigger UPDATELOG@
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATELOG
AFTER UPDATE OF STOCK_QTY ON STOCK
REFERENCING OLD AS O
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN
    IF O.STOCK_QTY < (SELECT STOCK_QTY FROM STOCK WHERE STOCK_ID = O.STOCK_ID) THEN
        --STOCKIN
        INSERT INTO LOG VALUES (
            GENERATE_UNIQUE(),
            'Stock-in',
            ((SELECT STOCK_QTY FROM STOCK WHERE STOCK_ID = O.STOCK_ID) - O.STOCK_QTY), 
            CURRENT DATE,
            NULL,
            O.STOCK_ID
        );
        --UPDATE STOCK
        --SET STOCK_QTY = STOCK_QTY - (SELECT ORDER_QTY FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND ORDER.STOCK_ID = STOCK.STOCK_ID);
    ELSEIF O.STOCK_QTY > (SELECT STOCK_QTY FROM STOCK WHERE STOCK_ID = O.STOCK_ID) THEN
        --STOCKOUT
        INSERT INTO LOG VALUES (
            GENERATE_UNIQUE(),
            'Stock-out',
            (O.STOCK_QTY - (SELECT STOCK_QTY FROM STOCK WHERE STOCK_ID = O.STOCK_ID)), 
            CURRENT DATE,
            (SELECT DELIVERY_ID FROM DELIVERY D, ORDER WHERE D.ORDER_ID = ORDER.ORDER_ID AND ORDER.STOCK_ID = O.STOCK_ID),
            O.STOCK_ID
        );
        END IF;
END@
```

I read the documentation on the SQLCODE and SQLSTATE for the error, and it says that the error is with the trigger and some select statement which return more than 1 value.

However when tested all the select statement (subqueries and queries) in trigger, it all return only 1 value, which is working without error.

```
ERROR:
An error occurred in a triggered SQL statement
 in trigger "PCNAME.UPDATELOG". 
Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-811", 
SQLSTATE "21000" and message token "", SQLSTATE "09000"
```

PS: Please help me by guiding me to do the correct thing with explanation instead of giving me just straightforward answer, my brain got stuck in this SQL traffic. If I cant learn anything from this lesson then I'm officially doomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message is quite explicit: as you correctly said, it complains about a `SELECT` statement returning more than one row in a context where only a single value is expected, typically in an assignment or scalar comparison. It also tells you that the problem occurs in the trigger named `PCNAME.UPDATELOG`.

Looking at that trigger's source you can see five subselects used in scalar contexts. Four of them select from `STOCK` by `STOCK_ID`, which is the primary key and therefore returns only one row by definition. Therefore, it's the remaining statement:

```
SELECT DELIVERY_ID FROM DELIVERY D, ORDER 
  WHERE D.ORDER_ID = ORDER.ORDER_ID AND ORDER.STOCK_ID = O.STOCK_ID
```

that is likely causing the issue. Since you are joining `ORDER` and `DELIVERY` by `ORDER_ID`, this query will return as many rows as there are deliveries for a particular order.

Comment: This might be the real problem with the code, I have to try it out first, thank you. By the way, I tried creating 3 dummy tables (A,B,C with two columns in each table) and 2 trigger(X,Y and X fire Y) that are meant to cascade. But it doesn't work out the way I expect.

Comment: Thank you again because that is exactly the error in my code, now I created a temporary table temp where I temporarily store the unique ORDER_ID from DELIVERY table to be used on UPDATELOG trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got enverything right from your question but here are some points to consider:

- Your trigger REQUEST_DELIVERY will never fire UPDATESTOCK_STOCKOUT 
  REQUEST_DELIVERY will execute an INSERT and UPDATESTOCK_STOCKOUT is waiting for an update
- Regarding the error with multiple rows returned - your have to guarantee that the only one row is returned. You could try to filter to a single PK value or use fetch first 1 row only or something like that.

Comment: REQUEST_DELIVERY will not fire UPDATESTOCK_STOCKOUT or UPDATELOG. But for the second point you pointed out might be the problem I missed, thank you.